# Passing Gridview Data to Modal Dialog (bootstrap)

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I am stucked with this problem for days, hope to get some advise... 
recently I have been working on school assignment and there is a requirement to put data from Gridview into modal dialog in order to edit it ,and i tried on several methods and it still cant works..

Asp.net (front):

```
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductLabel" HeaderText="ProductLabel" SortExpression="ProductLabel" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityStock" HeaderText="QuantityStock" SortExpression="QuantityStock" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="DateCreated" SortExpression="DateCreated" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateModified" HeaderText="DateModified" SortExpression="DateModified" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantitySold" HeaderText="QuantitySold" SortExpression="QuantitySold" />
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
```

P/S: I tried to set my modal dialog textbox.text with the data called at the code behind but still cant works.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried and tell us where the problem is.

Comment: will add the code soon